# Debug and fix stuttering system

Tags: windows-7, laptop, graphics-card, battery, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a notebook, Fujitsu Amilo Xi3670

```
Notebook: Fujitsu Amilo Xi3670
Processor: Intel Core 2 Quad Q9000
Graphics Adapter 1: NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT
Graphics Adapter 2: NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT
Display: 18.4 inch, 16:10, 1920x1080 pixels, glossy: yes
```

It's a big and powerful machine but it's no fun to work with it at the moment.

This is what I can tell you:

- VGA of Nvidia did work once, after one random night it did not anymore;
- System starts to stutter at random times. The mouse stutters when moved, video stutters and audio makes REALLY creepy sounds;
- No high CPU Usage!
- This happens on desktop, playing video or using any other program;
- Sometimes everything is good, doesn't happen that often;
- The Battery is not detected by the System if I use the AC. If I start the system with battery - everything is fine until a certain point when the battery is not detected anymore;

The worst problem is the stuttering.

**Please watch [this video](http://youtu.be/wSFhObBs7U4) so you know what I mean**

Do you have any ideas that point me in the right direction? I know it can be anything from corrupted hardware to bad drivers. Any tool I can test with?

Comment: Your another debug option could be to try running [Ubuntu live system](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install), give it some good usage - watch videos, do some CPU intense tasks, etc while carefully observing its performance. If everything is good - than we know the issue is your current OS. If system will be stuttering - than issue within your hardware. I would start with check.

Comment: i'll give that a try but i think i've already done that in the past.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. Used Lubuntu from CD and installed flash player via terminal. Mouse and video stutter, no audio glitches yet.

Comment: It does seem like the graphics cards are not behaving properly, can you disable them and just use the on-board graphics card ?

Comment: I've already tried that and disabled them in the bios, no luck there. Could it be a PSU Problem since the Battery is dead and it occours so randomly?

Answer (score 0):

On my first thought it seems like you have a process which sometime slow down the computer, did you install some software before this happening ?

- Check the process currently running, which run at computer start.
- Try to have a Windows repair for trying to identify the problem.
- It can be a driver (sound/graphical) issue maybe

Comment: I already tried fresh installations of win7 32 and 64bit with and without software. Every hardware i dont need is deactivated in the hardware manager

Comment: What about drivers version ?

Comment: since i have problems on linux live cd too, i doubt this has anything to do with drivers.